# How to run a created python program for different samples in a for-loop?

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, for-loop

I have a python program which is designed to take an `inputfile (containing data for multiple samples)`. Data for multiple samples are stored separately so can be accessed by submitting `sample name as --s`

```
$python2.7 calc_something.py --i inputfile.txt --s sample01  --p1 parameters --p2  para2 --o output_sample01
```

I want to run this for each sample in a for-loop by providing the sample name. Something like:

```
samples = ['sample01', 'sample02', 'sample03'...]
# creates a list of samples I want to input

# then  I want to do:
for x in samples:
    python2.7 calc_something.py --i inputfile.txt --s x  --p1 parameters --p2  para2 --o 'output_'+x
```

How can I do this in bash vs. python? which one is efficient?

Comment: why bash. Just import the calc_something.py in another file and run however you want

Comment: Running multiple Python scripts will always be less efficient than running one Python script, but how *much* less efficient depends on how long `calc_something.py` takes to run.

Comment: @chepner : I want to run in a for loop because I have lots of file to process. I thought using forloop is a good idea . Calc_something.py might take 20 mins per sample

Comment: In that case, it doesn't matter. Adding 1 second of overhead to a 20-minute runtime is negligible.

Comment: @chepner : so, you think using forloop is good vs bad?

Comment: You'll use a loop no matter what language you choose. I'm saying it doesn't matter if you do this in `bash` or `python`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple:

```
for item in  sample01 sample02 sample03 ... 
do
    python2.7 calc_something.py --i inputfile.txt --s "$item"  --p1 parameters --p2  para2 --o "output_${item}"
done
```

Comment: Is it bash or python?

Comment: @everestial007 bash